# Setup travis ci cpp project

Tags: c++, makefile, travis-ci

I am trying to setup a travis integration to a private github project.
I have installed travis and authorized it.
I have added `.travis.yml` file to my repository with the following content:

```
language: cpp
script:
  - make
  - make test
```

And I have the following `Makefile`:

```
COMPILER := g++
COMPILER_FLAGS := --std=c++11 -Wall
SRCS := Commands.cpp signals.cpp smash.cpp
OBJS=$(subst .cpp,.o,$(SRCS))
HDRS := Commands.h signals.h
TESTS_INPUTS := $(wildcard test_input*.txt)
TESTS_OUTPUTS := $(subst input,output,$(TESTS_INPUTS))
SMASH_BIN := smash

test: $(TESTS_OUTPUTS)

$(TESTS_OUTPUTS): $(SMASH_BIN)
$(TESTS_OUTPUTS): test_output%.txt: test_input%.txt test_expected_output%.txt
    ./$(SMASH_BIN) < $(word 1, $^) > $@
    diff $@ $(word 2, $^)
    echo $(word 1, $^) ++PASSED++

$(SMASH_BIN): $(OBJS)
    $(COMPILER) $(COMPILER_FLAGS) $^ -o $@

$(OBJS): %.o: %.cpp
    $(COMPILER) $(COMPILER_FLAGS) -c $^

zip: $(SRCS) $(HDRS)
    zip $(SUBMITTERS).zip $^ submitters.txt Makefile

clean:
    rm -rf $(SMASH_BIN) $(OBJS) $(TESTS_OUTPUTS) 
    rm -rf $(SUBMITTERS).zip
```

Note that the `Makefile` works correctly when I am trying to build my project.

On the travis dashboard I see my project
[image]

If I click "Trigger a build" a message pops up saying "Hooray!
You’ve successfully triggered a build for OS-Winter20-21/HW1. Hold tight, it might take a moment to show up."

But I am waiting for a long time now and nothing changes (not in the repo's prs and not in the travis dashboard)

Comment: I don't see how we can help you with this. Suggest you contact Travis support?

Comment: @Botje Thought I might be doing something wrong with the `yml` file.. does everything seem right?

Comment: Any errors in the travis yml should fail the build, but you're not even seeing any builds.